# DistributedCache unable to access archives

Tags: hadoop

I am able to access individual files using DistributedCache but unable to access archives.
In the main method I am adding the archive as

```
DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new Path("/stocks.gz").toUri(), job.getConfiguration());
```

where /stocks.gz is in hdfs. In the mapper I use,

```
Path[] paths = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheArchives(context.getConfiguration());
File localFile = new File(paths[0].toString());
```

which throws the exception,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/-8696401910194823450_622739733_1347031628/localhost/stocks.gz (No such file or directory)
```

I am expecting the DistributedCache to unzip /stocks.gz and the mapper to use the underlying file, but it throws a FileNotFound exception.

DistributedCache.addCacheFile and DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles works correctly when passing a single file, however passing an archive does not work. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving the stocks.gz with the Absolute path.

```
DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new Path("<Absolute Path To>/stocks.gz").toUri(), job.getConfiguration());
```

Comment: I tried using hdfs://localhost:8020/stocks.gz, but it is giving the same exception.

Comment: Not that. I meant the Absolute Path to file in File System. Like /home/hadoop/data/stocks.gz

Comment: Not sure I understand that. "/stocks.gz" is the absolute path to the file in hdfs.

Comment: It should a path to the file in hdfs